# How to read byte data with a header with PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, stm32, pyserial, packet

I'm using Pyserial to read byte data, so I can't use a simple null byte or EOL character since that could be real data and not an EOL identifier.

I've decided to try to send 4 bytes as the 'start-of-frame' like so:
0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03

Seeing this sequence of bytes in the payload would be highly unlikely, so this is a good candidate.

The protocol is always the same:  HEADER + 4 bytes of payload.

I want to use PySerial to graph these as they're incoming in realtime, but I can't get the first bytes synchronized.

Here's the Python snippet

```
    if ser.isOpen():

        try:
            ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
            ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output
                     #and discard all that is in buffer
            numOfLines = 0

            while True:
                response = ser.read(8)
                print(response)
                if (response[0:3] == bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03')):
                    data = struct.unpack('f',response[4:8])
                    print("read data: " + str(data[0]))
                    numOfLines = numOfLines + 1
                else:
                    print("Error")

            ser.close()
        except Exception as e :
            print("error communicating...: " + str(e))

    else:
        print("cannot open serial port ")
```

And here's the microcontroller C code that's sending the serial data:

```
#define HEADER  0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03

typedef union Data{
uint32_t x32;
float xfl;
uint8_t x8[4];
}Data;



uint8_t _header[4] = {HEADER};

bool send_data(uint32_t data_f){

  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_L_GPIO_Port, LED_L_Pin);
  Data data;
  data.xfl = data_f;
  while(HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&_header, 4)!=HAL_OK);
  HAL_Delay(1);
  while(HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&data.x8, 4,100)!= HAL_OK);

return true;

}
```

And here's what the Python script outputs when `send_data` is called every 10ms:

```
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
Error
```

As you can see, the header is in there, but it's in an unpredictable element index.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing bytearrays of different sizes in your conditional. Thus it will *always* evaluate to `False`. Change the upper bound to 4 so that you get 4 bytes instead.

```py
>>> result = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x89\x88\x88M'
>>> response[0:3] == bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03') # Your condition
False
>>> response[0:4] == bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03') # Better version
True
>>>
```